# Displaying a product based on category value in table | Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I replaced the name "Product" with "Pack" in my application. I was wondering if it was possible to display certain products based on their category_id string value in the "packs" table, without a category table. (only using the packs table to organize each pack on the packs' index. **A pack can only belong to one category.**

I am currently trying to do this via this code in my PacksController:

```
def index
  @title = 'Products';
  @packs = Pack.includes(:category_id).group_by { |pack| pack.category_id }
end
```

And trying to display the pack if it has the same `:category_id` as the `do` .erb:

```
<% @packs.select { |pack| pack.category_id == 'sample-pack' }.each do %>
  <div class="col-md-4 pack-pad">
    <%= link_to pack_path(pack) do %>
      <%= image_tag("#{pack.art_link}", :alt => "Sample pack cover, album art", :width => 333, :height => 333, class: "feat-img") %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When I run this code I get an error: `Association named 'category_id' was not found on Pack; perhaps you misspelled it?` but I don't know if this is even a possible approach to doing this.

This is my db table for "packs":

```
  create_table "packs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "description"
    t.integer "price"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "pack_type"
    t.string "audio_embed"
    t.string "art_link"
    t.string "pack_class"
    t.string "sku"
    t.string "download_url"
    t.string "category_id"
  end
```

This is what I've seeded into the db "confidential are changed:

```
theHunt = Pack.create!(
  title: "The Hunt",
  description: "<description>",
  price: "25",
  pack_class: "Action",
  pack_type: "Paid",
  category_id: "sample-pack",
  sku: "samplePack1",
  art_link: "<path>",
  download_url: "<link>",
```

)

Comment: Does Pack have a category_id field in the db?

Comment: @hashrocket Yes, I've updated my question with the db table for packs.

Comment: Do you have a Category db?

Comment: Use Pack.includes(:category) instead of Pack.includes(:category_id)

Comment: @hashrocket No, I was actually wondering if there was a way to pull this off by simply detecting the string of an individual pack and displaying it if it matched the string on the `do` statement in the pack index.

Comment: Did you change all instances of Product with Pack?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes. My params look like this, in case it helps: `def pack_params
      params.require(:pack).permit(:art_link, :title, :description, :price, :pack_type, :pack_class, :audio_embed, :category_id, :download_url, :sku)
    end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove `includes(:category_id)` in your query and it should work fine. You are trying to eager load an association named `category_id` but it does not exist (and it is not a convention in Rails to have a association like that, it should be a foreign key).

```
@packs = Pack.all.group_by(&:category_id)
```

In views:

```
<% @packs['sample-pack'].each do |pack| %>
  <div class="col-md-4 pack-pad">
    <%= link_to pack_path(pack) do %>
      <%= image_tag("#{pack.art_link}", :alt => "Sample pack cover, album art", :width => 333, :height => 333, class: "feat-img") %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

You might have to handle some exceptional cases such as when there are no category id called "sample-pack". I leave it to you to deal with.